# Why radio button is not checked well? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I'm having trouble with setting a default checked radio button. I have an array in a state that has different country names. In the radio buttons, I want to make `countryToVisit` checked. After the implementation, `countryToVisit` is checked, but when I try to check a new button I have to do it twice. Also, if I wanted to check another button again, it automatically check `countryToVisit`

**Here is my code. Let me know if something is not clear**

```
    class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            countries: ['USA', 'UK', 'China', 'Japan', 'Canada'],
            countryToVisit: 'Japan'
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <h1>Where do you want to travel?</h1>

                {this.state.countries.map((country, index)=>{
                    if (this.state.countryToVisit === country){
                        return(
                            <>
                                <input type='radio' name='test' id={country} checked />
                                <label htmlFor={country}>{ country }</label>
                            </>
                        )
                    }else {
                        return(
                            <>
                                <input type='radio' name='test' id={country} />
                                <label htmlFor={country}>{ country }</label>
                            </>
                        )
                    }
                })}
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.state.smallArray.includes('russia')`

Comment: Before starting your big project check out the docs on  `map`:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @RobinZigmond It's now unchecked but when I try to check it it doesn't work

Comment: because you need an `onChange` handler that adds/removes the string from the array

Comment: @RobinZigmond Why do I need to modify the array?

Comment: because you're telling the radio button to be checked or not according to whether the item is in the array or not, so if you want it to respond to clicks they need to modify the array

Comment: @RobinZigmond  Check my edit please

Comment: @morganney Check my edit please

Comment: You have to change the countryToVisit state with onChange. So then your component will rerender and you will get what you want. 
onChange={()=> this.setState({...this.state, countryToVisit: country  }) }